# Mono.Cecil: cannot see child class

Tags: c#, inheritance, mono, mono.cecil

Say I have a class B that derives from the class A

```
B : A
```

When reading from the assembly using Mono.Cecil I can see A (the parent class) but I cannot see B.

```
 AssemblyDefinition assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(pathfile);
foreach (TypeDefinition type in assembly.MainModule.Types)
        {   
            foreach (MethodDefinition method in type.Methods)
            {
                Mono.Cecil.Cil.MethodBody mybody = method.Body;

                if (mybody != null)
                {
                    foreach (Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction ins in mybody.Instructions)
                    { // do stuff
}}}}
```

My test program output is then *pathfile* - in the above code - and looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged.Create())
        {
            aes.GenerateKey();
        }
    }
```

In that example, I can see the class AES (parent class), but not the AESManaged one (child class). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to be much more specific about what exactly are you doing. You should include source of the assembly you're reading and also the code you're using to read it. See also [mcve].

Comment: Per the documentation, [AesManaged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged) is defined in `System.Core`, [Aes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.aes) is defined in `mscorlib`. You're not, by any chance, expecting to find them in one and the same assembly?

Comment: Which class are you looking for? Which assembly is it located in? Which class is its base class? Which assembly is that class located in?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm just expecting to load my main assembly and therefore any Types/References within it, irrespective of where the class is defined.

Comment: I'm looking for "AesManaged", I can only see its parent class "Aes" though.

Comment: Are you looking for all types *referenced* in an assembly, or all types *defined* in an assembly? It looks like you want the former, but your code is getting the latter (which is also why it will never find `Aes` and `AesManaged` at the same time, since those don't live in the same assembly).

Comment: oh I see, yup I'd like to see any type referenced. How should I do?

Comment: This still doesn't make sense to me. If you use that code while setting `pathfile` to your test program, then `assembly.MainModule.Types` will contain `Program` (or whatever the class that contains `Main` is called), but certainly not `System.Security.Cryptography.Aes`.

Comment: http://imgur.com/iiZWUF9
maybe that'll make more sense, as you can see Create() is visible in the _'Instructions'_ object. But it says 'Aes' whereas it should be AesManaged (the child class).

Answer (score 0):

Your specific question should really be why this piece of code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var aes = System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged.Create())
    {
        aes.GenerateKey();
    }
}
```

Compiles to the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  call        System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // aes
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // aes
IL_0007:  callvirt    System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm.GenerateKey
IL_000C:  leave.s     IL_0018
IL_000E:  ldloc.0     // aes
IL_000F:  brfalse.s   IL_0017
IL_0011:  ldloc.0     // aes
IL_0012:  callvirt    System.IDisposable.Dispose
IL_0017:  endfinally  
IL_0018:  ret
```

(Note: no mention of `AesManaged` anywhere.)

This happens because `AesManaged` doesn't have a static method named `Create`, `Aes` does. The C# compiler lets you call this method by referencing the derived class, but on the IL level, the method is part of `Aes` and `Aes` only. For the same reason, `aes.GenerateKey()` is compiled as a call to the method `SymmetricAlgorithm.GenerateKey`, since that's where the method's actually defined. (This is true even though `AesManaged` overrides this method.)

Now, what you want do to do with this depends on your scenario. If your objective is to get the class references as they are actually used by the IL, then your existing code does what you want. If, on the other hand, you want to get the references as they are in the source code, you'll have to use another method (like analyzing it with Roslyn).

Comment: That makes sense. That said, as per Microsoft website: "If the Windows security policy setting for Federal Information Processing Standards (FIPS)-compliant algorithms is enabled, using this algorithm throws a CryptographicException." and this is what I'm interested in. My code should throw an exception right? If so then I guess I'll have to give Roselyn a try, if Cecil is not of enough help here :)

Comment: I like how with every step we're getting closer to your *real* question. So is your *real* question "how do I analyze my code statically to make sure there are no possible FIPS violations"? Because that will take a little more than just detecting the use of `AesManaged`. (But a start could be to detect any call to `Aes.Create()` without an argument, and this can be done perfectly well on the IL level.)

Comment: That happens because you've taken quite a few assumptions here and there, as to what the "real question/issue" is. As a matter of a fact, FIPS compliance assessment could absolutely start with AESManaged class detection, not only the Create() method. That being said I guess you have point, I could certainly spot any function that would be used on a newly created AESManaged object, as a workaround. Though I was more interested in understanding how I could get Mono.Cecil to detect any class (irrespective of inheritance).

Comment: Well, the answer to that is, it *does* detect any class, but it does so on the IL level. If you go for detecting `AesManaged` in code, this will fail if the code calls `Aes.Create()`, because that yields an instance of `AesManaged` -- but it isn't documented to do so anywhere. Conversely, looking for `AesManaged` in the IL will fail, but the call to `Aes.Create()` will still yield a violation. Mono.Cecil doesn't "see" the child class because it *just isn't there*.